# Zabbix shows me multiple alerts for the same problem

Tags: zabbix

I have a Server Zabbix in which I am testing the monitoring, I have two Host the same zabbix server and the application of apache, create the hosts with the templates of website zabbix. So when I restart the hosts server zabbix or apache, in the section of problems I have these mensages which mean the hosts were restart, as you can see, I get the same message several times after having solved it.
[problem alerts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAlxH.jpg)

How can I make it only show me an alert?

Answer (score 0):

This alert checks if a server's uptime is below 10min, but it does it every minute so it'll trigger an alert every time. You can leave it as it is and it will automatically close after 10min.

If you want to change how long it shows, you can go to Configuration> Templates. There you'll have to select the template you used for the hosts, click on your alert and change the expression to trigger the alert when the uptime is below whatever time you prefer.

Comment: The solution was to reduce the time from 10m to 100s, I don't know if this was correct but it worked

Answer (score 0):

This is the [setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x067W.png) of trigger, according to the expression it obtains the last recorded value of an element which is specified which establishes a time condition of minus 10m, but as you know the expression is sent every minute